# How can I include or not include based on Scala version during cross compilation?

Tags: scala

I have some Scala code I'm trying to cross-compile against 2.11 and 2.12 versions.

In one file I have something like this (as an example):

```
import scala.language.existentials
```

Scala 2.11 requires this include to be present or my compile fails.  Version 2.12 fails unless I remove this include (it's "unused" according to the compiler).

Is there a way to annotate or otherwise flag this include to be compiled or not based on Scala version?  If not---what's a good way to handle this?

Comment: What is the failure message (the compiler error)? I would expect unused import to be at most warning, if it is reported at all.

Comment: I can't compile right now for unrelated reasons.  It's an error.  Using 2.12.6.  I noted that 2.13 is super-picky about such things too, so maybe this started in the latest 2.12 series?  Not a bad thing IMO, but there are a few cases where something needed by 2.11 is not needed/wanted by 2.12+

Comment: I think your question about how to use code depending on Scala version is good, but I am unable to reproduce the issue with the `scala.language.existentials`. My Scala 2.12.6 project is compiling fine both with and without it.

Comment: The only way I forced the compiler to produce a warning (not an error) was using `-Ywarn-unused-import` option.

Comment: Please, provide a minimal source. I have tried various experiments with existential types and in all cases both 2.11.12 and 2.12.6 behaved identically, and the compiler never gave me an error, only a warning.

Comment: I think I found my challenge:  Someone (likely me) added this to the build settings: -Xfatal-warnings  I think this will convert warnings to errors, and is probably the source of my difficulty.